# Regex - Get everything after, but not including, this character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an Id String which is appended to the end of the current pages URL, like so:

```
www.website.com?id=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want to get the Id from the end of the URL, so I want to end up with just

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

At the moment I have this:

```
var the_url;
var the_id;

the_id = the_url.replace(/^[^=]+/,"");

console.log(the_id);
```

But that is giving me this:

```
=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

How do I get everything after the equals sign, but not including the equals sign?

The Id itself is composed of random letters and numbers each time it is generated, so using any part of that for reference isn't really an option.

Comment: You don't need regexes for that, if you are sure that there is only 1 variable in the url: `the_id = the_url.split('=')[1];`

Comment: @funkwurm that's a great solution, cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `=` symbol next to the negated character class. So that only `=` also got removed.

```
the_url.replace(/^[^=]+=/,"");
```

OR

```
> var s = "www.website.com?id=XXXXXXXXXXXX";
undefined
> s.match(/[^=]+$/)
[ 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  index: 19,
  input: 'www.website.com?id=XXXXXXXXXXXX' ]
> s.match(/[^=]+$/)[0]
'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

`[^=]+` matches any character but not of `=` symbol one or more times. `$` anchors refers the end of a line.

Comment: Does the anchor `^` represent both beginning of line and negate?

Comment: Unescaped `^` outside the character class `[..]` represents the start of a line. `^` inside the character class at very first like `[^...]` would do the negation. But if the `^` is present anywhere else inside the char class other than start, it would match the literal `^` symbol. ex `[fo^]`, `[f^o]`